# Chest on Kaer Morhen scaffolding

Tags: the-witcher-3

Exploring Kaer Morhen I saw interesting chest inside one of the towers. However, all my attempts to get to it end up with Geralt falling to his death.

Is it possible to get to that chest at all, or is it just pure decoration?

[image: Chest]

[image: Chest location]

Comment: Heh :D That must be the flight of stairs that collapsed when Geralt was running away from Salamander thugs. Eskel and Lambert were supposed to fix it but they said they weren't masons. _Ah, the memories..._

Comment: I've played every DLC to this at least twice through, and made a habit of going everywhere I could on all the maps. I can run around on some mountaintops in Skellige that don't look like they're supposed to be reachable, and yet I can't get up here. That includes climbing the parapets visible on the right of your picture and trying to jump onto the scaffold, or jumping straight up to the parapets on the higher tower. Given that, I'm pretty sure it's not reachable, short of a mod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have stated shown with the screenshots, that chest is not reachable, but serves as a throwback as mentioned by @Gallifreyan. I also looked into the witcher 3 strategy guide, and that chest isn't mentioned.